# How to group dates by columns instead of going straight down?

Tags: database, ms-access, report

These are some imaginary accounts with totals for each category per month
[image: These are some imaginary accounts with totals for each category per month,] but I want the dates to appear like this:
[image: New set up]

How can I do this in a MS Access Report? (the above is in excel)

I tried this putting a second date next to the first like so:
[image: Another setup]

The box with format in it is the date.

I was hoping to find that it would work but this is what happened:
[image: Result]

Also tried putting the date into the main header as per [How to group within groups in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180816/how-to-group-within-groups-in-access)

This happened:
[image: Next result]

Comment: Try building a cross-tab query with hobbies as the rows and month name in the columns.

Comment: Building a stable report based on CROSSTAB is tricky. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#ColHead and https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/crosstab-report/index.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using A Crosstab On A Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448896/using-a-crosstab-on-a-report)